# My PC becomes very slow after changing page file in XP

Tags: windows-xp, pagefile

I have 5 partitions in my computer (C, D, E, F, G), and C: is the system partition.

Recently I changed the page file setting to use 768-768 MB from the G:, without changing the C: default value (256-512 MB).

Everything runs fine until I rebooted my PC.

I unset the G:'s page file before I rebooted my PC.

---

Well, after I rebooted my PC, my XP becomes VERY slow. damn slow.

I don't know how long I wasted to wait for the boot screen to disappear. (Well, maybe about 1-3 mins. Normally it is under 10 secs)

and when I tried to enter the desktop, it just like using a computer without a VGA card, or VGA driver installed. Very slow.

Any suggestions to fix this problem?

Because I hate to repair-install my XP =\

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP does an excellent job managing the virtual memory.

change the settings back to **System managed size**.

you should also defragment pagefile.sys (e.g. with Sysinternals' **[PageDefrag](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897426.aspx)**).

*PageDefrag is freeware and portable.*

p.s.: there is no benefit in using pagefile.sys on different partitions, unless you're using different physical disks (with IDE disks you will have to use the disks on different controllers to see any improvement).

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the recommended page file size is 1.5 times the physical main memory RAM. Since you now have less then half the size of the Page File, this could be the problem. If your C disk is very fragmented, you will have a problem allocating the page file continuously so the system becomes slower. Also, if the page file has to grow on a fragmented disk, the system is slower probably as well.